# How to make JInternalFrame(s) in JDesktopPane non-overlapping

Tags: java, overlapping, jinternalframe, jdesktoppane

I have multiple JInternalFrame(s) inside a JDesktopPane. All the JInternalFrame(s) are undecorated and I manage the dragging using mouse listeners. However, I want the internal frames to be non overlapping, i.e., one internal frame should not intersect with another.

Till now, I can check if two internal frames are overlapping by using getBounds().intersects() method. However, I am clueless as to what should I do next.

I tried Google but got no satisfactory answer. Please suggest a solution.

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

**Two answers:**

1. If you want to set which internal frame overlaps the other, use the setComponentZOrder(Component comp, int index) function.

e.g.

```
JDesktopPane desktopPane = new JDesktopPane();
contentPane.add(desktopPane);
JInternalFrame internalFrame = new JInternalFrame("New JInternalFrame");
desktopPane.add(internalFrame);
desktopPane.setComponentZOrder(internalFrame, 0);
```

Place the setComponentZOrder function in the JInternalFrame component listener.

```
    internalFrame.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void componentMoved(ComponentEvent e) {
            desktopPane.setComponentZOrder(internalFrame, 0);
        }
    });
```

2. If you want them to strictly not overlap, place them in separate jframes.

Comment: Your answer is to create a new top-level window? That doesn't seem right at all. I'm pretty sure he wants all the internal frames in 1 top level window

Comment: He/She clearly mentioned that he/she wants the JInternalFrame in the JDesktopPane.  I simply answered the question and made the variables accordingly. This being said, the ancestor of the JInternalFrame is arbitrary, as long as you use setComponentZOrder. If you want the ancestor to be contentPane, do contentPane.setComponentZOrder(internalFrame, 0);